# Vector output from instance on points

Tags: node-editor, geometry, instances, vector

I need some help with the following problem. I want to create a rope between two points. This works perfect when I use two objects. I want a static end point (Empty) and a point on a mesh as start point. For example, a cube with 8 vertices that creates 8 ropes to a point. See picture. It must be procedural with use of geometry nodes. How do I create a location output from point of a mesh?

What I get:
[image: wrong]

What I want:
[image: correct]

Problem:
[image]

Anyone?

Dave

Answer (score 2):

i have simplified your question, so i just created "straight" lines from empty to each vertex of the cube:

[image]

of course you can do this with a more complicated curve as well. I just wanted to show you a way to do it.

Comment: In addition this video lays the concept of simulating gravity with curves using a trick on the control point handles https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k65ofSRnxfs